# Netty - Channel write fail to send the data to the client

Tags: java, netty

I am developing a socket based app using Netty 3.6.x. However I am encountering an issue with the channel.write. This is what I did:
First whenever the channel goes to the CONNECTED state I write to the channel and it is successful. Now when the server goes done I try reconnect to it and when the channel is connected I try write to it but this time it seems that the server did not receive the data.

Also when I check the write state it say done.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the ChannelFuture was failed and if so inspect the the error via:

```
ChannelFuture future = ...
if (!future.isSuccess()) {
    future.getCause().printStacktrace();
}
```

This should show you the reason why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Norman. I have fixed the issue. 
The issue was that I was using the the ChannelFuture listener and I realized that I was setting the pipeline and the transcoder within that callback. So when I sent the data over the wire it is not encoded properly. To solve I have to handle every in the channelConnected and channelCLosed method.